# Unable to connect MySQL hosts with MySQL-Front

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to connect my web project using vs2010 c# with mysql database using MySql-Front, before this I'm using xampp phpMyadmin and I use this query;

```
"User Id=root;Server=localhost;Database=myDB"
```

to connect my database but I can't use it when I tried it with MySql-Front. How can I connect my database with MySql-Front? I've never use MySql-Front before, is there any way to do it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I already know how to connect my new database, I only need to know new address for my database, so I only need to change the query;

```
"Server = myServer; Database = myDB; Uid = myUsername; Pwd = myPassword"
```